# How do I create multiple new datasets that remove the NAs from select variables?

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, tapply

I have a dataset that I want to break into several datasets using one of the apply functions

The dataset that has two observations per class_id, one from the district and one from the teacher. I need to create 6 new datasets that remove both the district and class observation if either one of them is NA.

[image: My data currently look like this:]

and in this scenario I would need 3 new datasets

[image: Var 1 dataset would look like this]

[image: Var2 would look like this]

[image: Var 3 would look like this]

I am trying to work with sapply or another apply function but I am having no luck

```
data.list<- test1 %>%
       sapply(test1[, c(11:16)], funs(group_by(class_id), filter(!any(i== "NA"))
```

Comment: To me, it's not very clear how the datasets are divided into new ones?  The three examples you posted still carry the `NA`s. Is that your expected output?

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).